# limit value and LH rule

Tags: limits

L=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x^4}$ and L is finite. What is the value of a ?

After using LH rule,

we get L=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{1}{2}}{4x^2}$, since L is finite, we make the numerator zero i.e a=2. Which make L=0.

But when we apply a=2 directly to L=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x^4}$ i.e

L=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x^4}$

L=$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(2-\frac{x^2}{4})^2-(4-x^2)}{x^4(2-\frac{x^2}{4}+\sqrt{4-x^2})}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(4+\frac{x^4}{16}-x^2)-(4-x^2)}{x^4(2-0+2)}=\frac{x^4}{16}\frac{1}{x^4 4}$
, we get L as $\frac{1}{64}$

Which is the true value L=0 or L=$\frac{1}{64}$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=2$ does not give you $L=0$. You just make the numerator $0$ at $x=0$ but when you take the limit of the ratio as $ x\to 0$ you still have an indeterminate form and you have to apply L'Hopital's Rule to get the limit. The correct limit is $\frac  1 {64}$.